# business logic in domain objects

Tags: java, performance, design-patterns, concurrency

Having this class:

```
public class DataPeriod {

private final String key;
private final LocalDate from;
private final LocalDate to;

private final Map<LocalDate, DataPoint> dataPoints = new HashMap<LocalDate, DataPoint>();

public DataPeriod(String key, LocalDate from, LocalDate to) {
    this.key = key;
    this.from = from;
    this.to = to;
}

public LocalDate getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public LocalDate getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void hit(int id) {
    DataPoint dataPoint = getOrCreate();
    dataPoint.hit(id);
}

private DataPoint getOrCreate() {
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    String dataPointKey = key + now.toString();
    if ( !dataPoints.containsKey(now) ) {
        DataPoint dataPoint = new DataPoint(dataPointKey);
        dataPoints.put(now, dataPoint);
    }

    return dataPoints.get(dataPointKey);
}

public long count() {
    long count = 0l;
    for (DataPoint dataPoint : dataPoints.values()) {
        count += dataPoint.count();
    }
    return count;
}
```

Could be a good idea extract the methods `hit(int id)` and `getOrCreate()` to some other class as a service or helper. But then they should be modified in order to receive parameter for `DataPoint`.

I think has sense include them into `DataPoint`class because they represent actions which `DataPeriod`must know.

There is some pattern for that scenario? In terms of concurrency extract or not extract these methods makes any difference?

Comment: I don't completely understand your example but is it practically possible for `LocalDate.now();` to return the same value for two consecutive calls? If no, what's the point of `!dataPoints.containsKey(now)`?

Comment: `LocalDate`  represents a date without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to leave the methods in the same model class if they only use data inside the same class, or in other words, if they don't depend on other classes.

Of course you will never access services from a model class, but sometimes it is difficult to decide if a model class should use another model class. It depends on whether the relation is tight (e.g. one contains the other, and the contained class will never be used independently). If two model classes are not strongly related then one should not manage the other; in that case I would leave the work for a third external class (like a service or simply another model class *containing* the others).

In your case, the `DataPeriod` contains the `dataPoints` (which could be another model class) so I think it's fine to leave the methods there.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a classic case for use of ***dynamic attributes***.
If you have an attribute that can be computed from other attributes then declare it as a *dynamic* attribute and write a custom *attribute handler* for it.
 *For example*- If you have a *persistent* attribute (the one that you store in a database), like *date of birth* then you can declare a *dynamic* attribute *age* and compute it at runtime without storing it in the database. You will need a custom *dynamic attribute handler* like `AgeAttributeHandler.java`.
 Another motivation for having *dynamic attributes* is the spring bean convention that all model beans ***must*** have ***only*** *getters* and *setters*. The *business logic* should be kept outside the model beans.

 In your case, first create a `DynamicAttributeHandler.java`-

```
public interface DynamicAttributeHandler<VALUE, MODEL extends Object> {
    VALUE get(MODEL var1);

    void set(MODEL var1, VALUE var2);
}
```

Then, create *dynamic attribute handlers* for `count` and `dataPoints`.

```
public class CountAttributeHandler implements DynamicAttributeHandler<Long, DatePeriod> {

    @Override
    public Long get(DatePeriod model) {
        long count = 0l;
        Map<LocalDate, DataPoint> dataPoints = model.getDataPoints();
        for (DataPoint dataPoint : dataPoints.values()) {
            count += dataPoint.count();
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(DatePeriod model, Long aLong) {

    }
}

public class DataPointsAttributeHandler implements DynamicAttributeHandler<Map<LocalDate, DataPoint>, DatePeriod> {

    @Override
    public Map<LocalDate, DataPoint> get(DatePeriod model) {
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        String dataPointKey = model.getKey() + now.toString();
        Map<LocalDate, DataPoint> dataPoints = model.getDataPoints();
        if (!dataPoints.containsKey(now)) {
            DataPoint dataPoint = new DataPoint(dataPointKey);
            dataPoints.put(now, dataPoint);
        }
        return dataPoints;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(DatePeriod model, Map<LocalDate, DataPoint> localDateDataPointMap) {

    }
}
```

Now, the model can be created with just *getters* and *setters*.

```
public class DatePeriod {

    private final String key;
    private final LocalDate from;
    private final LocalDate to;
    private final Map<LocalDate, DataPoint> dataPoints;
    private final long count;

    public DatePeriod(String key, LocalDate from, LocalDate to, Map<LocalDate, DataPoint> dataPoints, long count) {
        this.key = key;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.dataPoints = dataPoints;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public LocalDate getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public LocalDate getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public Map<LocalDate, DataPoint> getDataPoints() {
        DynamicAttributeHandler<Map<LocalDate, DataPoint>, DatePeriod> dataPointsAttributeHandler = new DataPointsAttributeHandler();
        return dataPointsAttributeHandler.get(this);
    }

    public long getCount() {
        DynamicAttributeHandler<Long, DatePeriod> countAttributeHandler = new CountAttributeHandler();
        return countAttributeHandler.get(this);
    }
}
```